# understanding enqueue in a linked list

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, queue, singly-linked-list

hey i am trying to add to my queue but I have a problem, and I need some help
i used a linked list for my queue and the problem is when I add a 3rd item to my list I overwrite the second 
this is the code

```
void addnode(node* data)
{
    if (begin == NULL)
    {
        data->next = begin;
        begin = data;
    }
    else
    {
        end = data; //this is where the problem when i add a 3rd data i dont save anywhere my end so its gone
        begin->next = end;
        end->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

in my code i have begin for the start of the queue, and end for the end of it

the linked list i built is with classes in c++,
but whenever i add a 3rd data the second gets overwriten so i always have two..
I need some help with how to fix it, thanks :)

edit this is more of the code: this is my class for the queue

```
#include"node.h"
class queue
{
public:
    queue();
    ~queue();
    void addNode(node*);
private:
    node* begin;
    node* end;

};
```

this is the class that i get the data from

```
using namespace std;
class node
{
    friend void printclient(node &);
public:
    node();
    ~node();
    void setstr(string);
    void setmoney(int);
    node* next;
private:
    string name;
    double money;
    int id;
};
```

Comment: what `end` pointer stands for?

Comment: Please show sufficient code. `begin` and `end` are undefined, as is the structure of `node`.

Comment: i posted an edit

Comment: @shahar Unfortunately the edit is not sufficient. For instance, where is `next` defined? Please carefully read the [help for posting questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: now its ok i hope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function can look the following way. I suppose that the data member `next` of the node pointed to by the pointer `data` is already set to `nullptr`.

```
void addnode(node* data)
{
    if (begin == nullptr)
    {
        begin = end = data;
    }
    else
    {
        end = end->next = data;
    }
}
```

That is if the queue is empty (the pointers `begin` and `end` are equal to nullptr) then begin and end are set to the added pointer.

Otherwise the new node is appended to the end of the queue. In this case the data member next of the node pointed to by the pointer end is set to the new pointer and this pointer becomes the end pointer.

Pay attention to that the user of the queue should know nothing about the class node. The class should be declared as a private or protected member of the class queue. And the method addNode should be substitute for the method push declaration of which should look like

```
void push( const std::string &name, int id, double money );
```

Comment: thanks it works.. can you explain to me why i dont need to set my begin->next?

Comment: @shahar When the list is empty and you added one node to it then the both pointers begin and end point to the same node. So if you will changed the data member next of the node using the pointer end then it is the same if to use the pointer begin. But as you always are adding new node to the end of the list there is no need to use the pointer begin.